# Oracle: How to sum up alias column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have a query:

```sql
SELECT od.*, i.name AS item_name, (od.quantity*od.price) AS sub_total
    FROM order_details od
    JOIN items i ON od.item_id = i.item_id
    WHERE order_id = 9
```

It produces the following result.
[image]

Now, I want to sum up `SUB_TOTAL` column and I want the result as `1300`.

I've tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```sql
SELECT od.*, i.name AS item_name, (od.quantity*od.price) AS sub_total, SUM(sub_total) AS total
    FROM order_details od
    JOIN items i ON od.item_id = i.item_id
    WHERE order_id = 9
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a window `SUM()` - and you can't reuse the column alias, you need to repeat the expression, or use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT od.*, i.name AS item_name, (od.quantity * od.price) AS sub_total,
    SUM(od.quantity * od.price) OVER() AS total
FROM order_details od
JOIN items i ON od.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE order_id = 9
```

You might need to adjust the `OVER()` clause of the window `SUM()` according to your actual requirement. The above query will bring `1300` on both rows. You can use a `PARTITION BY` clause to divide the set of rows into groups, and/or use `ORDER BY` to compute a running sum.

Comment: Thank you. It works. And really thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT od.*, i.name AS item_name, (od.quantity*od.price) AS sub_total,
       SUM((od.quantity*od.price) OVER (ORDER BY order_detail_id)
FROM order_details od JOIn
     items i
     ON od.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE order_id = 9;
```

Note that you cannot re-use the alias; you need to repeat the calculation.